How do I insert an ip address check in front of a php-served application using nginx?
I have a running website (php-based) that sits behind nginx being served directly, not a reverse proxy. The basic nginx is below:
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name my.server.com;

    index index.php;

    root /var/www/myserver/public; 

    location /client {
        root /var/www/myserver; 
        autoindex off;

        location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|svg|svgz|jpeg|gif|ico|tpl)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/index.php last; break;
        }
    }
}

When a user navigates to the site to login, before they are presented with the index.php that will allow login, I'd like to verify their IP address, before serving the index.php; denying access if it inappropriate or continuing normal processing if it is appropriate. Blacklist and Whtelist won't work as everyone gets at least one chance to try to access.
I'd like something like the following to run at the homepage at session start:
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9017; # ip gate service
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

What is the appropriate way to do this?

Better use a firewall for that, it's more secure and more performance friendly. I recommend the tool fail2ban, it uses iptables to block inappropriate access. You can configure the inappropriate access violations by yourself. Read its documentation.
